# Como foi desenvolvido o CSS?

Tags: css, css3

Estou tentando descobrir, mas estou a tempo pesquisando e não encontrei nenhuma referência, alguém teria uma ideia de como foi desenvolvido o CSS?

Foi desenvolvido com alguma linguagem especifica? Qual tecnologia utilizada?

Comment: Como assim? O CSS é uma especificação, cada implementação de interpretador/renderizador usa a linguagem que quiser.

Comment: Mas como foi desenvolvido esta regra? alguma linguagem? qual tecnologia?

Comment: Um comitê se reuniu e decidiu como o CSS deveria funcionar. Provavelmente usaram um editor de texto :) Talvez alguma outra ferramenta para representação de linguagens formais. Você já viu a especificação do CSS?

Comment: Sim, eu li, mas não ficou claro como estas especificações são criadas, como as regras são aplicadas nos navegadores, não encontrei nada na web que informe com clareza como o CSS realmente funcione e quais tecnologias usadas para cria-lo.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets#History

Comment: https://tableless.com.br/uma-breve-historia-do-css/